# Calculate the sum of dynamic cloned forms for Profit and Loss in javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a Simple Profit and Loss page for my sales. The goal is:

1. One row equals One client.
2. Add a dynamic row based on number of clients.
3. For each row I need to input the sale amount and cost amount, then calculate the profit for that row(client).
4. Calculate the sum of all rows profit.

The issue: When I add a row, the button calculates only the first DOM row and not the result of the cloned ones as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addForm").click(function() {
    $("#pnl").clone().appendTo(".originalPnlDiv");
  });

});


function calculate() {
    var salesPnl = document.getElementsbyClassName('sale').value;
    var costPnl = document.getElementsbyClassName('cost').value;
    var sum = document.getElementById('total').value = salesPnl - costPnl;

}

function totalProfit() {
    var totalSalesPnl = document.getElementsbyClassName('sale').value;
    var totalCostPnl = document.getElementsbyClassName('cost').value;
    var totalSum = document.getElementById('grandTotal').value = totalSalesPnl - totalCostPnl;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>PNL</h1>

  <div class="originalPnlDiv">
    <form action="" id="pnl">
      <select>
        <option value="customerZ">customerZ</option>
        <option value="customerX">customerX</option>
      </select>
      <input class="sale" type="number" placeholder="sale S$">
      <input class="cost" type="number" placeholder="cost S$">
      <input placeholder="invoice#">
      <input type="date">
      <input id="total"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button id="addForm">Clone</button>
  <button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
  <br>
  <br>
<button onclick="totalProfit()">Total Profit</button>
<p>The totalprofit is <span id="grandTotal"></span></p>
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I am only two months old regarding coding.

Have a nice day

Comment: Try searching [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for `getElementsByTagName` to find what it returns - it doesn't have a 'value' property.

Answer (score 1):

1. don't use `id` when it's not going to be unique across the page.
2. re-organize your logic by moving the calculate button for each line
3. use `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addForm").click(function() {
    $("#pnl").clone().appendTo(".originalPnlDiv");
  });

});


function calculate(button) {
  var form = button.closest("form");

  var salesPnl = form.querySelector('.sale').value;
  var costPnl = form.querySelector('.cost').value;
  var sum = salesPnl - costPnl;
  form.querySelector('#total').value = sum;
  return sum;

}

function totalProfit() {

  var parent = document.querySelector(".originalPnlDiv");
  var panels = parent.querySelectorAll("#pnl")
  var grand = 0;
  panels.forEach(function(panel) {

    grand += calculate(panel);
  })
  document.querySelector("#grandTotal").innerText = grand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>PNL</h1>

<div class="originalPnlDiv">
  <form action="" id="pnl">
    <select>
      <option value="customerZ">customerZ</option>
      <option value="customerX">customerX</option>
    </select>
    <input class="sale" type="number" placeholder="sale S$">
    <input class="cost" type="number" placeholder="cost S$">
    <input placeholder="invoice#">
    <input type="date">
    <input id="total" />
    <button onclick="calculate(this); return false">calculate</button>
  </form>
</div>
<button id="addForm">Clone</button>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick="totalProfit()">Total Profit</button>
<p>The totalprofit is <span id="grandTotal"></span></p>
```